# Tikzcd with Beamer: extremely simple code results in & ampersand catcode error

Tags: beamer, errors, tikz-cd, catcodes, ampersand

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile, t]{My slides}
\only<1>{
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
a 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}}
\only<2>{
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
a  \arrow{r} &  b
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

All I want is to show 'a' first, then a point to b, like this 'a->b' (and it has to use Tikz-cd!). But Tikzcd is making it impossible because I get the following error:

> Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.
>
> See the pgf package documentation for explanation. Type  H  
>   for immediate help.  ...
>                                                      l.13 \end{equation*}}
>                         This error message was generated by an \errmessage command, so I can't give any explicit help. Pretend that
>   you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues, and deduce the truth by
>   order and method.

Is there any way to solve this issue? The  &  works fine when it is on its own frame. But when I put it into a \only block things go bonkers.

I thought [fragile] was supposed to prevent these things!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normal ampersand (`&`) does not work well with `beamer`, so you have to change it. I change to `\&`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile, t]{My slides}
\only<1>{
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
a 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}}
\only<2>{
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
a  \arrow{r} \&  b
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I didn't try that solution because I thought this was for the case when you actually want to write an ampersand. I thought Tikzcd is using that ampersand as an anchor to the next node

Comment: @Themanofyourdream Ti*k*Z-cd is, literally, a Ti*k*Z matrix, nothing more.

Comment: I'm guessing that the `&` issue here comes from the fact that the tikzcd is being used inside a macro and that closses the catcodes prematurely.

Comment: @daleif I have very little knowledge with `beamer`, so I can't explain it fully. But after some issues I had to deal with, and looking at some questions here, I  found that `&` and `beamer` are not friends.

Comment: @JouleV it has nothing to do with `beamer`, try wrapping an `tikzcd` env in the following command: `\newcommand\test[1]{#1}` you get the same issue, and the same solution.